# How does the Byte Order Fallacy code work?

Tags: endianness

In [this article](https://commandcenter.blogspot.fi/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html), titled *The byte order fallacy*, the author states that worrying about the endianness of the system your code runs on is unnecessary. The article has been mentioned in [a few places on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=byte%20order%20fallacy) as well. In the article, the author posits that as long as you know the endianness of your data stream, you can use the following snippets to handle it automatically:

Little-endian stream:

```
i = (data[0]<<0) | (data[1]<<8) | (data[2]<<16) | (data[3]<<24);
```

Big-endian stream:

```
i = (data[3]<<0) | (data[2]<<8) | (data[1]<<16) | (data[0]<<24);
```

As the author does not explain any of this, I have two questions: one, *how does this actually work*? And two: how would one *reverse this, without checking the endianness* of the system (if even possible in the first place)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippets work, because the bitshift operators operate on the number as if it was big-endian, regardless of the endianness. This means, that bitshifting `0x1234` to the right by 4 bits on both a big-endian and a little-endian machine will result in the number that represents `0x0123`.

This also works to the left, i.e. `0x1234 << 4 == 0x12340`, within the limitations of integer size.

The reverse, i.e. writing to a stream with a given endianness, can be done by using right-shifts instead of left-shifts to decompose the integer:

```
char buf[4] = {x, x >> 8, x >> 16, x >> 24}; // Little-endian
char fub[4] = {x >> 24, x >> 16, x >> 8, x}; // Big-endian
```